# Anime where an elf mother is being killed

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching a short video at YouTube named villains aren't born they are made where a elf mother was being dragged by soldiers then killed the house elf was living in had no electricity or any modern technology and the human soldiers who killed her was using swords and they had no modern technology too can you help me identify the anime?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is the title exactly "Villains aren't born they are made?"  When did you see this?

Comment: If you know the name of the YouTube channel or the video, please provide a link to it, so we can view it for ourselves.